# Volume of a closed and orientable manifold is positive

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $g_{ij} dx^i \otimes dx^j$  be a Riemannian metric on an orientable and closed manifold $M$ (dimension $n$). Let $dvolg=\sqrt{det(g_{ij})} dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$. Show $\int_M dvolg>0$. I wonder where does the "closedness" of $M$ come in the proof. Or do we need the manifold to be "closed" at all?

Comment: Note that it is tacitly assumed that $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ is an orientation-compatible chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Closed" in this context means "compact without boundary." If the manifold is not compact, there is no guarantee that the volume is finite. But if the volume is finite, then the conclusion still holds.

I suspect that whoever wrote the problem was working in a context where integrals of differential forms had been defined either on compact manifolds with or without boundary, or for compactly supported differential forms. If $M$ is noncompact, then neither of these conditions holds, and you have to interpret the integral as an improper integral (for example, defined as the limit over compact subdomains, or something like that).

Comment: So all we need is compactness? Can you shed a light on how to go about the proof?

Comment: A good place to start is to make sure you understand the definitions. What's the definition of an orientable manifold? What does orientability have to do with coordinate charts? What's the definition of the integral of an $n$-form over an orientable $n$-manifold? Once you understand those definitions, together with the formula you wrote down for $dvol_g$, that should give you a pretty good idea of how to go about proving the claim.

Comment: I was stuck on why it is strictly positive. Now I realized (correct me if I'm wrong) that the piece I missed was partition of unity.